# Update Array attribute using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN stack application in which i defined a model using following schema:

```
var mappingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    MainName: String,
    Addr: String,
    Mapping1: [Schema1],
    Mappings2: [Schema2]
},
{collection : 'Mappings'} 
);
```

I am displaying all this data on UI and `Mapping1` & `Mapping2` are displayed in the 2 tables where I can edit the values. What I am trying to do is once I update the values in table I should update them in database. I wrote `put()` api where I am getting these two updated mappings in the form of object but not able to update it in database. I tried using `findAndModify()` & `findOneAndUpdate()` but failed.
Here are the Schema1 & Schema2:

```
const Schema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,
    Variable: String
});

const Schema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
    SName: String,
    Provider: String
});
```

and my put api:

```
.put(function(req, res){

  var query = {MainName: req.params.mainname};

        var mapp = {Mapping1: req.params.mapping1, Mapping2: req.params.mapping2};

        Mappings.findOneAndUpdate(
            query, 
            {$set:mapp}, 
            {}, 
            function(err, object) {
                if (err){
                    console.warn(err.message);  // returns error if no matching object found
                }else{
                    console.log(object);
                }
            });                
    });
```

Please suggest the best to way update those two arrays.

**UPDATE** : 
I tried this

```
var mapp = {'Mapping2': req.params.mapping2};

        Mappings.update( query , 
                           mapp , 
                        { },
                        function (err, object) {
                            if (err || !object) {
                                console.log(err);
                                res.json({
                                    status: 400,
                                    message: "Unable to update" + err

                                });
                            } else {
                                return res.json(object);
                            }
                        });
```

what I got is [image: this]

My array with size 3 is saved as String in Mapping2 array.

Please help. Stuck badly. :(

Answer (score 0):

From [Mongoose's documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate) I believe there's no need to use `$set`. Just pass an object with the properties to update :

```
Mappings.findOneAndUpdate(
      query, 
      mapp,  // Object containing the keys to update
      function(err, object) {...}
 );
```

Comment: Its give following on console : 'Cast to embedded failed for value "\'[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]\'" at path "Mappings1"
PUT /api/mapping/Test%20Model/%5Bobject%20Object%5D,%5Bobject%20Object%5D,%5Bobject%20Object%5D/%5Bobject%20Object%5D,%5Bobject%20Object%5D,%5Bobject%20Object%5D,%5Bobject%20Object%5D 200 41.067 ms - 159'